# VBA: filter a column by type instead of values

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have an excel file with a column that should be filled with dates only, but there might be strings or Nothing in some cells. Is there any way to filter the data by type and not value, so that I can delete the unwanted rows?

I didn't find any operator in the autofilter method that would do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub FilterLeavingJustTheDates()
 Set m = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

 If Not IsDate(m.Value) Then
  m.Value = ""
 End If

 Do
  n = n + 1

  Set m = m.Offset(1, 0)
  Set r = m.Resize(5, 1)
  b = False
  For Each cell In r
   If cell.Value <> "" Then
    b = True
   End If
  Next cell

  If Not IsDate(m.Value) Then
   m.Value = ""
  End If
 Loop Until b = False

 Range("A1:A" & n).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
End Sub
```